# Merge dataframes base on Column and Row values

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that I'd like to merge with another dataframe with the same column values. Also with specified row values.

Dataframe 1

```
d = {'id': ['111', '222', '333'], 'queries': ['High', 'Mid', 'Low'], 'time_stay': ['High', 'Mid', 'Low']}
dd = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Dataframe 2

```
l = {'Features': ['queries', 'queries', 'queries', 'time_stay', 'time_stay', 'time_stay'], 'groups':['High', 'Mid', 'Low', 'High', 'Mid', 'Low'], 'parameters':[1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 1000, 2000, 3000]}
feature_data = pd.DataFrame(data=l)
feature_data
```

I pivoted dataframe 2 to make the first row as columns.

```
feature_data = feature_data.T
feature_data.columns = feature_data.loc['Features', :]
```

Then I merged it
`dd.merge(feature_data, on=list(feature_data.columns), how='left')`
As expected, pandas doesn't let me merge it because column `queries` is duplicated.

Expected output

[image]

What's a better way to do this ? thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of what you expect the final result to be?

Comment: I added expected output @dm2

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, is there a reason not to merge the original dd and feature_data as `dd.merge(feature_data, left_on = 'queries', right_on = 'groups')` ?

Comment: @dm2 the `features` of `feature_data` may contain other values than `queries`. Therefore, needs to also filter the column values

Comment: @dm2 I updated the example data to make it more complete.

Comment: Ok yeah, I see it's a bit more complicated than it seemed at first. I'll keep it in mind but for now no 'clean' way comes to mind.

Comment: In row 1 expected output, how do we know the `parameter` is 1.2 instead of 1000 (`time_stay==High`)? I guess I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter for column values in `feature_data` dataframe and then merge it to `dd` dataframe

```
cols_name = 'queries'
queries = feature_data[feature_data['Features']==cols_name]
dd.merge(queries[['groups','parameters']],
         left_on=['queries'],
         right_on=['groups'],
         how="left")
        .drop(columns='groups')
print(dd)

id  queries time_stay   parameters
111 High    High        1.2
222 Mid     Mid         1.1
333 Low     Low         1.0
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use f-strings for `queries` in `feature_data.query("Features == 'queries'")` ?  So I can use a loop to iterate it.

Comment: I checked the documents, it says I can use `@` to refer to variables so I tried  `feature_data.query("Features ==@variable")` but I got syntax error

Comment: Adjusted the filtering code for column name, you can now use loop, and it should work.